# Очень странное поведение компьютера

Tags: windows

у меня что-то с пк. Когда тестирую в furmark, cinebench(opengl, и cpu) всё нормально. Как только захожу в любую игру твориться что-то не ладное... На мониторе пишет No signal detected, потом монитор выключается, потом горит чёрный экран и потом появляется рабочий стол, и свёрнутая игра. Видеокарта рабочая, на другом компе с этой же видюхой такого нет. Пробовал переустановить Windows 10, не помогает.

Comment: Попробуй переустановить драйвера

Comment: Берём OCCT PT и по вкладке Power Supply гоняем с час, следим за охлаждением. Результаты в комментарии.